# If $G=G_1\times G_2$ does it follow that $H\leq G \implies H=H_1\times H_2$ where $H_1\leq G_1$ and $H_2\leq G_2$

Tags: group-theory

If $G=G_1\times G_2$ does it follow that $H\leq G \implies H=H_1\times H_2$ where $H_1\leq G_1$ and $H_2\leq G_2$. I am thinking that it does, being that the projection of $H$ into $G_1$ and $G_2$ is a homomorphism, but now that I am writing this it might be that $H\subset H_1\times H_2$ rather than equality.

Comment: With different letters the same question was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1006305/669).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the case $G_1=G_2$ and $H=\{\,(g,g):g\in G\,\}$.